# soapUI getPropertyNames returns nothing

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I have created properties at project, testsuite and test case level.

At test case level, I created a groovy script with

```
String[] props = context.getPropertyNames()
for (prop in props) {
     log.info prop
}
```

It executes but output in log window is weird :

```
 INFO:RunCount
 INFO:log
 INFO:Thread Index
```

Why I can't see the properties I created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the properties(from groovy script) defined at

Test Case level:

`def testCaseProperties = testRunner.testCase.properties
log.info "Test Case Properties :\n$testCaseProperties"`

If you want value of certain property
`log.info testCaseProperties.getPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME')`

Or

`log.info context.expand('${#TestCase#PROPERTY_NAME}')`

Test Suite Level:

`def testSuiteProperties = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.properties
log.info "Test Suite Properties :\n$testSuiteProperties"`

Project Level:

`def projectProperties = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.properties
log.info "Project Properties :\n$projectProperties"`

Similarly you may use context to get certain property value available at different level by
`context.expand('${#TestSuite#PROPERTY_NAME_OF_SUITE}')`
`context.expand('${#Project#PROPERTY_NAME_OF_PROJECT}')`
for suite, project respectively